# HTML5 and short-closing tags

Tags: html, syntax

Is it bad practice to close tags that don't have closing tag with the "old" XHTML syntax?
e.g.
`<link/>`, `<meta/>` etc

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In HTML5 the possibility to use self closing tags on void elements (like `<meta>`, `<img>`, `<br>`, `<input>`, etc) was added to ease migration to and from XML but it is not necessary.

Answer (score 1):

The HTML spec is designed so that later versions will support their predecessors' syntax.

I suspect it's more of a matter of taste than correctness.